# How to remove/move vertically running editor from canopy python environment?

Tags: python, canopy

I prefer canopy for only running python script. I am not sure if I can remove the running editor space from the canopy window. If there is any option to move the running editor into a vertical position. I also fine with that.

Please let me know if this thing is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, currently it's not possible to remove the file editor space. The phrase "vertical position" is ambiguous (do you mean vertically above/below the python panel, or do you mean aligned to be tall rather than wide?) Whichever way you meant, the answer is "yes, you can", by dragging its title bar as described at the bottom of [this section of the user guide](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#code-editor-python-shell-and-file-browser).

You say that you only want to use Canopy to run scripts.So you never want to edit the scripts that you are running? If that's true, you might try running the scripts from a Canopy Command Prompt or Terminal (reachable from the Tools menu).

Comment: Thank you so much. :) @Jonathan-March